# Class that holds calculation results and has to be immutable

Tags: java, immutability

I'm roughly trying to follow the guidelines in "Effective Java", "Item 15: Minimize mutability", hence the class is not "final" on purpose.

Information is gathered from a number of temperature meters.
Some may fail to report, so the size of the map is not known.

The serializing bothers me. Is there a simpler way to make this class immutable ?

```
public class Result<T extends Number> {
    private final Map<String, T> result;

    private Result(final Map<String, T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public static final Result<Number> of() {
        return new Result<>(new LinkedHashMap<>());
    }

    /** Add or replace value. */
    public Result<T> put(final String key, final T value) {
        final Map<String, T> copy = new LinkedHashMap<>(result);
        copy.put(key, value);
        return new Result<>(copy);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T get(final String key) throws Exception {
        return ((T) convertFromBytes(convertToBytes(result.get(key))));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return result.toString();
    }

    private byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
            out.writeObject(object);
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    private Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))) {
            return in.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your class is not immutable because the `Map` given in the constructor is not copied (and `Map` itself isn't immutable). You should instead have a constructor like

```
public Result(final Map<String, T> result) {
    this.result = new LinkedHashMap<>(result);
}
```

What's the goal of the `of()` method ? Shouldn't it be named `empty()` instead ?

```
public static final Result<Number> empty() {
    return new Result<>(new LinkedHashMap<>());
}
```

Or having two parameters (1 key, 1 value) ?

```
public static final Result<Number> of(final String key, final T value) {
    Map<String, T> base = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    base.put(key, value);
    return new Result<>(base);
}
```

The fact that `get()` throws an `IOException` or a `ClassNotFoundException` bothers me because it makes the current underlying implementation "leaking" out of your class. Who wants (and expects) to have to handle an `IOException` when getting a value from a `Map` ?
Since these exceptions are not supposed to happen in this case, I would rethrow them as unchecked exceptions

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T get(final String key) throws Exception {
    try {
        return ((T) convertFromBytes(convertToBytes(result.get(key))));
    } 
    catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: changed constructor to private.

Comment: of() method was supposed to replace the constructor (since it is now private)

Comment: @user77115 So why not naming this method `empty()` ? I've always encountered `of(something)` methods. See [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for example.

Comment: changed to Exception.

Comment: this of() business is takenfrom Effective Java AFAICR. just following that template.

Comment: @user77115 I also made my point clearer about the exceptions